# Screen Capture with WebRTC on Android

Tags: java, android, webrtc

I'm trying to make a peer-to-peer screen sharing application. In the code example below, when I start screen sharing, the application crashes. Where am I doing wrong?

When I start screen sharing, a warning notification appears on the screen and returns result code -1 even though I accept the notification.

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
> android.media.projection.MediaProjection.registerCallback(android.media.projection.MediaProjection$Callback,
> android.os.Handler)' on a null object reference

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode != CAPTURE_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE)
        return;
    mMediaProjectionPermissionResultCode = resultCode;
    mMediaProjectionPermissionResultData = data;
}

@TargetApi(21)
private void startScreenCapture() {
    MediaProjectionManager mediaProjectionManager =
            (MediaProjectionManager) getApplication().getSystemService(
                    Context.MEDIA_PROJECTION_SERVICE);
    startActivityForResult(
            mediaProjectionManager.createScreenCaptureIntent(), CAPTURE_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
}

@TargetApi(21)
private VideoCapturer createScreenCapturer() {
    if (mMediaProjectionPermissionResultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        Log.d(TAG, "User didn't give permission to capture the screen.");
        return null;
    }
    return new ScreenCapturerAndroid(
            mMediaProjectionPermissionResultData, new MediaProjection.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onStop() {
            Log.d(TAG, "User revoked permission to capture the screen.");
        }
    });
}

private void getUserMedia() {
    Log.d(TAG, "getUserMedia");

    // Initialize the PeerConnectionFactory globals
    PeerConnectionFactory.InitializationOptions initializationOptions = PeerConnectionFactory.InitializationOptions
            .builder(this)
            .setEnableInternalTracer(true)
            .createInitializationOptions();
    PeerConnectionFactory.initialize(initializationOptions);

    // Create a new PeerConnectionFactory instance
    PeerConnectionFactory.Options options = new PeerConnectionFactory.Options();
    options.networkIgnoreMask = 16; // ADAPTER_TYPE_LOOPBACK
    options.disableNetworkMonitor = true;
    mPeerConnectionFactory = PeerConnectionFactory.builder()
            .setOptions(options)
            .setVideoEncoderFactory(new DefaultVideoEncoderFactory(mRootEglBase.getEglBaseContext(), false, false))
            .setVideoDecoderFactory(new DefaultVideoDecoderFactory(mRootEglBase.getEglBaseContext()))
            .createPeerConnectionFactory();




    // Create VideoSource and VideoTrack instances
    VideoSource videoSource = mPeerConnectionFactory.createVideoSource(false);
    mLocalVideoTrack = mPeerConnectionFactory.createVideoTrack("WebRTC_track_v1", videoSource);
    mLocalVideoTrack.setEnabled(true);

    // Create AudioSource and AudioTrack instances
    AudioSource audioSource = mPeerConnectionFactory.createAudioSource(new MediaConstraints());
    mLocalAudioTrack = mPeerConnectionFactory.createAudioTrack("WebRTC_track_a1", audioSource);
    mLocalAudioTrack.setEnabled(true);

    // Initialize the VideoCapturer
    SurfaceTextureHelper surfaceTextureHelper = SurfaceTextureHelper.create("CaptureThreadOne", mRootEglBase.getEglBaseContext());



    //mCameraCapturer = CameraCapturer.create(true, true);
    //mCameraCapturer.initialize(surfaceTextureHelper, this, videoSource.getCapturerObserver());
    startScreenCapture();
    videoCapturer = createScreenCapturer();
    // videoCapturer.initialize(surfaceTextureHelper, this, videoSource.getCapturerObserver());

    // Start recording
    //mCameraCapturer.startCapture(640, 480, 30);
    videoCapturer.startCapture(640,480,30);
    mLocalVideoTrack.addSink(mLocalVideoView);

    // Try to initiate a call
    sendMessage("got user media");
    if(mIsInitiator) {
        initiateCall();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you been able to resolve this?

Comment: @decades Yes, I solved it, but because time passed, I forgot that project.